# ARM bare-metal with MMU: successive reads yield different values

Tags: memory, arm, mmu, bare-metal

**Context (probably not needed):**

As a learning exercise, I'm trying to implement a mini "OS" for the Raspberry Pi.

I'm currently implementing a very dumb memory management system. I already have the MMU enabled, and I'm in the process of getting a usable kmalloc.

It can already allocate chunks of memory from a pre-existing little kernel heap, mapped after the code and data segments. I'm trying to get it to grow as needed by mapping more pages. It must also be able to produce physically contiguous chunks.

The code is hosted at [Github](https://github.com/Pikrass/pios/tree/so-17981923), there's a branch dedicated to this question with debug code. Note that it's not an example of well-organized, well-commented nor very clever code. :)

**Actual question:**

While trying to debug a data abort, I found something very strange.

This is a piece of code from my kmalloc:

```
next->prev_size = chunk->size;
next->size = -1;

term_printf(term, "A chunk->next_free = 0x%x\n", chunk->next_free);
term_printf(term, "B chunk->next_free = 0x%x\n", chunk->next_free);

*prev_list = next;
next->next_free = chunk->next_free;

term_printf(term, "next_free = 0x%x, chunk 0x%x\n", next->next_free, chunk->next_free);
term_printf(term, "next_free = 0x%x, chunk 0x%x\n", next->next_free, chunk->next_free);
```

I run it three times. Here are the results:

```
# 1st
A chunk->next_free = 0x0
B chunk->next_free = 0x0
next_free = 0x0, chunk 0x0
next_free = 0x0, chunk 0x0

# 2nd
A chunk->next_free = 0xffffffff
B chunk->next_free = 0x0
next_free = 0x0, chunk 0xffffffff
next_free = 0x0, chunk 0x0

# 3rd
A chunk->next_free = 0xffffffff
B chunk->next_free = 0xffffffff
next_free = 0xffffffff, chunk 0xffffffff
next_free = 0xffffffff, chunk 0xffffffff
```

The first and third iterations look normal (though next_free is supposed to have the value 0, the data abort occurs because it's got 0xffffffff). But what is my code doing during the second? O_o What kind of black sorcery can make my printf output two different values for chunk->next_free when read four times in a row? O_o

The data is well aligned, the pages are cacheable and non-bufferable (making them non-cacheable doesn't help), and I get the same result whether compiler optimizations are turned on or off. I tried throwing a data memory barrier in there but indeed it does nothing. I also checked the assembly produced, it looks ok.

I thought it could be caused by corrupted TLBs. I'm issuing "Invalidate unified single entry" (mcr p15, 0, %[addr], c8, c7, 1) after each new page mapping. Is it enough?

I tried debugging with qemu but it gets a data abort earlier when setting a bitmap of used physical pages, though this part works fine on the Pi.

I'm just looking for clues about what can cause this behavior. If you need more context please ask, though my code is for the moment rapidly changing and messy with lots of printf.

---

ETA:
The disassembly with -O0 for the first two printf:

```
c00025e4:       e51b3018        ldr     r3, [fp, #-24]
c00025e8:       e5933008        ldr     r3, [r3, #8]
c00025ec:       e59b0004        ldr     r0, [fp, #4]
c00025f0:       e59f10a0        ldr     r1, [pc, #160]  ; c0002698 <kmalloc_wilderness+0x2c0>
c00025f4:       e1a02003        mov     r2, r3
c00025f8:       eb000238        bl      c0002ee0 <term_printf>
c00025fc:       e51b3018        ldr     r3, [fp, #-24]
c0002600:       e5933008        ldr     r3, [r3, #8]
c0002604:       e59b0004        ldr     r0, [fp, #4]
c0002608:       e59f1088        ldr     r1, [pc, #140]  ; c000269c <kmalloc_wilderness+0x2c4>
c000260c:       e1a02003        mov     r2, r3
c0002610:       eb000232        bl      c0002ee0 <term_printf>
```

So it puts the address of `chunk` into r3, then perform a `ldr` to get `next_free`. It does it again before the second prinf. There's only one core, the DMA is not running, so there's nothing changing the value in memory between the calls.

With -O2:

```
c0001c38:       e1a00006        mov     r0, r6
c0001c3c:       e59f10d8        ldr     r1, [pc, #216]  ; c0001d1c <kmalloc_wilderness+0x1b8>
c0001c40:       e5942008        ldr     r2, [r4, #8]
c0001c44:       eb000278        bl      c000262c <term_printf>
c0001c48:       e1a00006        mov     r0, r6
c0001c4c:       e59f10cc        ldr     r1, [pc, #204]  ; c0001d20 <kmalloc_wilderness+0x1bc>
c0001c50:       e5942008        ldr     r2, [r4, #8]
c0001c54:       eb000274        bl      c000262c <term_printf>
```

So it still fetches the value with `ldr`. That's why I get the same thing with both optimization levels.

---

New edit: I added more printfs, and it seems that the singularity happens at this point:

```
next->size = -1;
```

After this line, chunk->next_free turns into Heisenberg's cat. Before, it reads as 0.

The structure is defined as such:

```
struct kheap_chunk {
    size_t prev_size;
    size_t size; // -1 for wilderness chunk, bit 0 high if free
    struct kheap_chunk *next_free;
};
```

`chunk` and `next` don't overlap.

If I move the "singularity line" below the `next->next_free = chunk->next_free`, it stops alternating between two values, but it's still weird: chunk->next_free is 0 before `*prev_list = next`, 0xffffffff after that. But next->next_free is still set to 0.

Comment: You mentioned `term_printf` is written in assembly.  Are you sure it obeys the calling conventions your C compiler is expecting?

Comment: Yes, I've used it extensively with any number of arguments and it never showed any problem. I'm using arm-none-eabi-gcc.

Comment: you have disassembled and examined the calls to term_printf to know that the compiler is grabbing the right stuff?  likewise you have tried different optimization levels to see if that affects the behavior?

Comment: I investigated some more. See the third part of the question (and I added the previous lines in the source).

Comment: Ok, I added a condition, and it seems like term_printf is reporting 0xffffffff even though the value is indeed 0. So the problem must come from this function after all.

Comment: Even with a brand new term_printf (and term_print_hex) written in C I get this weird behavior. There's something there I must be doing terribly wrong.

Comment: You have to show more code. Preferably put your source on github.com or similar so one can download, compile and run it.

Comment: It's already on Github: the link is in the question. Note that the question is quite old and I've moved on to other projects. ;)